# neo4j return root node once, and all relationships and end-nodes in json

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to make a html view of everything known about a node.

So, if i were to select that node `n` and `RETURN n`, i'd get a json object with `n: { stuff ... }`, and if i also return its relationships and connected nodes `RETURN n,r,n2`, now i get a really verbose json object:

```
[
  {
    n: { originating node details },
    r: { relationship details },
    n2: { connected node details }
  },
  {
    n: { originating node details },
    r: { relationship details },
    n2: { connected node details }
  },
  {
    n: { originating node details },
    r: { relationship details },
    n2: { connected node details }
  }
]
```

Where the same exact data is in `n` a bunch of times. So, in theory, that'd be OK, and I could say `var seedNodeData = results[0].n` and use that as a way to get the main node data, before then separately iterating over all objects to list out the connecting node data. But, this seems like a waste of data transferred.

Currently, to limit that data, I just `RETURN r,n2` since the first one is always the same, but then I"d need to do a separate call to get `n`'s data.

Is there a way to make one call to get the info for `n` once, and then `[r]-(n2)` as many times as necessary and have it wrapped up into one cypher query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could aggregate the relationships and relatives into a collection.
Does something like this work for you?

```
match n-[r]->n2
with n, [type(r), n2] as relative
return { root: n, relatives: collect(relative) }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a collection of maps to describe each of the other nodes and the relationships that connect them.

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(o) WHERE ...
RETURN n AS node, labels(n) AS node_labels, COLLECT({rel: r, rel_type: type(r), other: o, other_labels: labels(o)}) AS relations
```

Using this `RETURN` statement, you only get your subject node (and its properties and labels) back once, along with a list of maps that describes the relationships (both type and properties included) and related nodes (both labels and properties included).

The output will be just one "row", structured like:

```
[
    {"subject_prop1": 1, "subject_prop2": 2, ...},
    ["SubjectLabel1", "SubjectLabel2", ...],
    [
        {
            "rel": {"rel_prop1": 1, "rel_prop2": 2, ...},
            "rel_type": "RELTYPE",
            "other": {"other_prop1": 1, "other_prop2": 2, ...},
            "other_labels": ["Label1", "Label2", ...],
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
]
```

(I excluded the Neo4j boilerplate from the structure.)